# Can I used RxJS-DOM over RxJS with Redux-Observable

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable, rxjs-dom

Redux-Observable has a dependency on RxJS.

I need to use the filereader function from RxJS-DOM.

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS-DOM/blob/master/doc/operators/filereader.md

It looks like RxJS-DOM contains the same basic set of APIs as RxJS (plus the DOM ones).

Is it possible to ask Redux-Observable to use RxJS-DOM rather than RxJS? Importing both is bloating the size of my build.

Comment: They claim to have a [procedure to write an adapter](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#general-rxjs-v4) for other RX implementations; haven't tried it myself!

Answer (score 3):

RxJS-DOM aka [rx-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rx-dom) is for RxJS v4, not for v5+. The two are **incompatible**. The situation is confusing, indeed.

- This is RxJS v4 and below: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rx
- This is RxJS v5+: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs

In v5+ there is no official equivalent to `fromReader`, here's the issue ticket tracking: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1223

Although probably not what you want to hear, creating custom Observable wrappers around other APIs *should be fairly simple* as long as you do understand how Observables fundamentally work. It's a pretty valuable skill to learn, regardless.

`fromReader` is actually a misnomer since you don't provide it a FileReader, you provide it a `File` and it internally creates its own `FileReader` to drain it. So let's say `fromFile` instead. This is a very basic starting point example:

```
class FromFileAsTextObservable extends Observable {
  constructor(file, encoding) {
    super();

    this.file = file;
    this.encoding = encoding;
  }

  _subscribe(subscriber) {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    const loadHandler = event => {
      subscriber.next(event.target.result);
      subscriber.complete();
    };

    const errorHandler = event => {
      subscriber.error(event.target.error);
    };

    reader.addEventListener('load', loadHandler, false);
    reader.addEventListener('error', errorHandler, false);

    reader.readAsText(this.file, this.encoding);

    return () => {
      reader.removeEventListener('load', loadHandler, false);
      reader.removeEventListener('error', errorHandler, false);
    };
  }
}

class FromFileFactory {
  constructor(file) {
    this.file = file;
  }

  asText(encoding) {
    return new FromFileAsTextObservable(this.file, encoding);
  }
}

const fromFile = file =>
  new FromFileFactory(file);

const file = new File(['hello world'], 'example.txt', {
  type: 'text/plain',
});

fromFile(file).asText()
  .subscribe(text => console.log(text));
```

While that's the more flexible way for complex APIs and such, if all you want to do is read a file and handle load/error, you could instead create an anonymous Observable like so:

```
const fromFileAsText = (file, encoding) => new Observable(subscriber => {
  const reader = new FileReader();

  const loadHandler = event => {
    subscriber.next(event.target.result);
    subscriber.complete();
  };

  const errorHandler = event => {
    subscriber.error(event.target.error);
  };

  reader.addEventListener('load', loadHandler, false);
  reader.addEventListener('error', errorHandler, false);

  reader.readAsText(file, encoding);

  return () => {
    reader.removeEventListener('load', loadHandler, false);
    reader.removeEventListener('error', errorHandler, false);
  };
});

const file = new File(['hello world'], 'example.txt', {
  type: 'text/plain',
});

fromFileAsText(file)
  .subscribe(text => console.log(text));
```

Comment: In my defense, I was young and reckless with my method names :P.

Comment: @paulpdaniels lololol you should be ashamed of yourself lololol